# Can twiml set a rate limit on responses?

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I have a number set up with a small twiml script (using twimlets). I want to have it stop responding for a bit if it's overused. For example if it's dialed 5 times in 1 minute it should wait 3 minutes before responding again. Is this possible with twiml/twimlets or would I need to move it to my own server and set up some code to detect this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Unfortunately I you't be able to set a rate limit just with TwiML. You could set a [time limit](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes-time-limit) for each call, but that wouldn't really accomplish exactly what you want.

My suggestion would be moving it to your own server where you will then be able to have full control of what your pages return, therefore showing different content according to the number of times it's been requested.

You can probably just spin up a free Heroku instance that will make things easier for you. [This page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/ios-client/setup) shows you how to do that and much more.